# Multilevel model: Contradictory results between multilevel model with interactions and segmented model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, glmmtmb, nonlinear-multilevel-analysis

I am working on a research paper exploring the differential effect (or interaction) of financialization on the housing conditions of the population according to tenure status. For this purpose, I decided to perform a multilevel analysis with the R package `glmmTMB`. The variables of interest are "precahabcat" (a measure of housing conditions), "HH021" (housing tenure), "Hipotecas_pop_cbst" (the number of mortgages granted between regions) and "Hipotecas_pop_cwst" (the number of mortgages granted within regions). In that case, HH021 could be interpreted at a first-level variable and both mortgage granting (between and within) as a second-level variable. For clarification, the latter two variables (mortgage granting) are standardized to facilitate convergence.

As I mentioned at the beginning, the objective is to see what impact the interaction of these two variables has on housing conditions. For this I have found that two possible options can be realised:

1. A cross-level interaction between mortgage granting (Hipotecas_pop) and housing tenure (HH021) on housing conditions (precahabcat).
2. Create different models, segmenting by HH021.

I have performed the two methods to see the consistency of the results and thus analyze the robustness, but I have found totally contradictory results. Here I will provide just one example for mortgaged homeowners (HH021 = 2)

In the first case, I found that there is a positive significant correlation (95% confidence level) in the interaction term between HH021 = 2 and Hipotecas_pop_cbst on precahabcat, but a negative significant association in the interaction between HH021 = 2 and Hipotecas_pop_cwst (contrary to expected).

This is the output:

```
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula:          precahabcat ~ factor(sexo) + edad_st + factor(hogar) + educst +  
    factor(income_quintiles) + factor(HH021) + factor(nacionalidad) +      factor(urb) + Annual_growth_pop_cbst + Annual_growth_pop_cwst +  
    urban_cbst + urban_cwst + Hipotecas_pop_cbst + Hipotecas_pop_cwst +  
    factor(DB010) + factor(HH021) * Hipotecas_pop_cbst + factor(HH021) *      Hipotecas_pop_cwst + (HH021 | id_y_ccaa) + (HH021 | DB040)
Data: dreg
Weights: pweights_b

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 17752.4  18124.8  -8834.2  17668.4    52412 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr  
 id_y_ccaa (Intercept) 0.105882 0.32539        
           HH021       0.007064 0.08405  -0.87 
 DB040     (Intercept) 0.074527 0.27300        
           HH021       0.005873 0.07663  -1.00 
Number of obs: 52454, groups:  id_y_ccaa, 74; DB040, 19

Conditional model:
                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                       -1.570332   0.202122   -7.77 7.90e-15 ***
factor(sexo)2                      0.098355   0.041267    2.38 0.017153 *  
edad_st                           -0.223171   0.025624   -8.71  < 2e-16 ***
factor(hogar)1                     0.161794   0.060005    2.70 0.007011 ** 
factor(hogar)2                    -0.025638   0.056896   -0.45 0.652273    
factor(hogar)3                     0.250296   0.108364    2.31 0.020901 *  
factor(hogar)4                     0.812661   0.066334   12.25  < 2e-16 ***
educst                            -0.160471   0.025064   -6.40 1.53e-10 ***
factor(income_quintiles)2         -0.987809   0.052836  -18.70  < 2e-16 ***
factor(income_quintiles)3         -2.908071   0.068421  -42.50  < 2e-16 ***
factor(income_quintiles)4         -3.388489   0.078353  -43.25  < 2e-16 ***
factor(income_quintiles)5         -3.705872   0.091656  -40.43  < 2e-16 ***
factor(HH021)2                     2.600387   0.067148   38.73  < 2e-16 ***
factor(HH021)3                     2.958326   0.082685   35.78  < 2e-16 ***
factor(HH021)4                     2.271907   0.118105   19.24  < 2e-16 ***
factor(HH021)5                     0.335183   0.131288    2.55 0.010679 *  
factor(nacionalidad)2              0.218129   0.097063    2.25 0.024622 *  
factor(nacionalidad)3              0.555520   0.077043    7.21 5.58e-13 ***
factor(urb)2                      -0.166671   0.048836   -3.41 0.000643 ***
Annual_growth_pop_cbst             0.140595   0.038483    3.65 0.000259 ***
Annual_growth_pop_cwst             0.024832   0.054063    0.46 0.646011    
urban_cbst                        -0.093539   0.046723   -2.00 0.045284 *  
urban_cwst                         0.033368   0.028746    1.16 0.245721    
Hipotecas_pop_cbst                -0.051146   0.066755   -0.77 0.443571    
Hipotecas_pop_cwst                 0.001776   0.116919    0.02 0.987878    
factor(DB010)2011                 -0.475151   0.225028   -2.11 0.034728 *  
factor(DB010)2015                 -0.295681   0.253915   -1.16 0.244226    
factor(DB010)2019                 -0.479964   0.249013   -1.93 0.053921 .  
factor(HH021)2:Hipotecas_pop_cbst  0.129782   0.053839    2.41 0.015928 *  
factor(HH021)3:Hipotecas_pop_cbst  0.081987   0.068917    1.19 0.234180    
factor(HH021)4:Hipotecas_pop_cbst  0.013255   0.104753    0.13 0.899309    
factor(HH021)5:Hipotecas_pop_cbst -0.068706   0.116016   -0.59 0.553710    
factor(HH021)2:Hipotecas_pop_cwst -0.119313   0.046487   -2.57 0.010271 *  
factor(HH021)3:Hipotecas_pop_cwst -0.149949   0.059642   -2.51 0.011932 *  
factor(HH021)4:Hipotecas_pop_cwst -0.162835   0.099685   -1.63 0.102364    
factor(HH021)5:Hipotecas_pop_cwst  0.069425   0.090698    0.77 0.444005    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, in the second case (in the segmentation), I found a positive significant correlation between Hipotecas_pop_cbst and precahbcat when I subsample for mortgage homeowners (HH021 = 2), but not negative for Hipotecas_pop_cwst.

This is the output:

```
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula:          precahabcat ~ factor(sexo) + edad_st + factor(hogar) + educst +  
    factor(income_quintiles) + factor(nacionalidad) + factor(urb) +      Annual_growth_pop_cbst + Annual_growth_pop_cwst + urban_cbst +  
    urban_cwst + Hipotecas_pop_cbst + Hipotecas_pop_cwst + factor(DB010) +      (1 | id_y_ccaa) + (1 | DB040)
Data: dregp
Weights: pweights_b

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  5754.7   5949.8  -2851.4   5702.7    13349 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id_y_ccaa (Intercept) 0.001007 0.03173 
 DB040     (Intercept) 0.022208 0.14902 
Number of obs: 13375, groups:  id_y_ccaa, 74; DB040, 19

Conditional model:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                2.08762    0.26510    7.87 3.42e-15 ***
factor(sexo)2              0.12771    0.07351    1.74 0.082350 .  
edad_st                   -0.20580    0.05666   -3.63 0.000281 ***
factor(hogar)1             0.14778    0.09989    1.48 0.139019    
factor(hogar)2            -0.17160    0.11520   -1.49 0.136333    
factor(hogar)3             0.08122    0.18412    0.44 0.659137    
factor(hogar)4             0.80460    0.12377    6.50 8.00e-11 ***
educst                    -0.13703    0.04355   -3.15 0.001652 ** 
factor(income_quintiles)2 -1.94198    0.12468  -15.58  < 2e-16 ***
factor(income_quintiles)3 -4.26544    0.13956  -30.56  < 2e-16 ***
factor(income_quintiles)4 -4.81414    0.14929  -32.25  < 2e-16 ***
factor(income_quintiles)5 -5.17924    0.16314  -31.75  < 2e-16 ***
factor(nacionalidad)2      0.70700    0.20972    3.37 0.000749 ***
factor(nacionalidad)3      1.00086    0.17218    5.81 6.14e-09 ***
factor(urb)2              -0.02173    0.08707   -0.25 0.802941    
Annual_growth_pop_cbst     0.04524    0.06055    0.75 0.454921    
Annual_growth_pop_cwst     0.06003    0.07274    0.83 0.409197    
urban_cbst                -0.20587    0.05851   -3.52 0.000433 ***
urban_cwst                -0.00243    0.03477   -0.07 0.944274    
Hipotecas_pop_cbst         0.15178    0.06107    2.49 0.012945 *  
Hipotecas_pop_cwst        -0.12742    0.12778   -1.00 0.318681    
factor(DB010)2011         -0.33474    0.26153   -1.28 0.200570    
factor(DB010)2015         -0.36561    0.29854   -1.22 0.220700    
factor(DB010)2019         -0.60948    0.29089   -2.10 0.036150 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In this regard, I would like to know which model I should look at and which one is more reliable, as well as what other faults there may be in the modelling.

Comment: Three things that stick out: 1) the first model output has a perfect negative correlation of random effects, indicating potential misfit of your model 2) you haven't properly explained all of the variables here, so it would be good to clarify what the rest mean here (for example the factor level hogar which has at least 4 coefficients) 3) this model has an obnoxious number of coefficients, so it might be good to justify why they are included in the first place and how they could be simplified if possible.

Comment: I agree with @ShawnHemelstrand, simplify your model. A good strategy for working with complicated models is to build up from simpler models so you understand how things change as you add more complexity. One thing that is clear is that the random effect correlation of -1 is a strong indication the random slope for HH021 at the level of DB040 is not needed.